# Why don't I have the File History aka command center in VS Code on title bar?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have vscode latest version (1.81.1 2023-08-09) installed on both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 22 Linux hosts.

On Windows, I can see the Quick File Navigation on top menu bar
[image]

When you click on it (1), it lists the recently worked files (2)
[image]

This is very handy.

However, vscode on Linux host doesn't have it.
[image]
I can use Ctrl+P to pop up it, but I cannot find a way to pin it to the top menu bar like it on Windows.

How can I pin the Quick File Navigation to the top menu bar?

Comment: No, that didn't answer my question. Mine answered its question. My question is better with example, screenshot,  and in better terminology. By the way, the input field is called Quick File Search on VSCODE site, see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved.

Comment: the document you linked does not talk about any feature named "quick file search". It does talk about "quick file navigation". But even that is a different feature, separate from the command center. Ironically, it is actually you who is using the wrong terminology. And the answer there actually _does_ answer this question. I particularly made sure of that when I designed it.

Comment: @starball, sorry, if I used wrong term. I appreciate that you helped me. But from a beginner's perspective, it (he/she) wouldn't know to search "command center". It would search "file history", because that was what it was looking for.  And "file history" would bring it to the link that I posted. You have to see from a beginner's perspective. If I knew it was called "command center", I would not have posted the question. If a beginner saw "comment center" in the title, it would skip the link. The title had to have "file" keyword in it.

Comment: I recognize that terminology is important in question design. I try to strike a balance, but I prefer for titles to use correct terminology (and weave "incorrect terminology" into the post body) unless the question's sole purpose is to help someone learn the right term. I've edited the proposed dup-target's body to include the phrase "file search".

Comment: thank  you for seeing from a different perspective. I agree that there needs a balance so that beginner can become professional eventually. When I searched for the answer, I wasn't aware of any command feature; I only needed to get the file-history feature. But after reading your answer, I realized that it packed with more than just file history. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the title bar style to "custom". Ex. in [settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson):

```json
"window.titleBarStyle": "custom",
```